# Can i made a text file (.txt) from my database data and store in on any particular folder on server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i have a task assigned that i have to create a text file ***(notepad)*** from database table **email** which have more than 12000 rows and each row have a email-id,the table just have ID int identity primary key and email nvarchar(500) columns.

i have done this in asp.net by creating a text file on server and  using stream writer write text file

now my question is

**Is it possible to create text file of data from sql server 2008.because i am using that version**

and one more thing i want one email-id in one row in .txt file ......

thanks buddies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can do it in .NET code, but if you want to do it in the SQL Layer, create an SSIS job, where you make the file and select what you need into it.
FYI: http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/ssis-exporting-data-to-a-text-file-using-a-package/